# Bash/Awk Compare two files, print value when it is between coordinates else print 0

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files. If the column "chromosome" matches between the two files and the position of File1 is between the Start_position and the End_position of File2, I would like to associate the two cell_frac values. If the Gene (chromosome + position) is not present in File2, I would like both cell_frac values to be equal to 0.

**File1:**

```
Hugo_Symbol Chromosome  Position
Gene1       1           111111
Gene2       1           222222
Gene3       2           333333
Gene4       2           333337
```

**File2:**

```
Chromosome  Start_Position  End_Position    cell_frac_A1    cell_frac_A2
1           222220          222230          0.12            0.01
2           333330          333340          0.03            0.25
3           444440          444450          0.01            0.01
```

**Desired output:**

```
Hugo_Symbol Chromosome  Position    cell_frac_A1    cell_frac_A2
Gene1       1           111111      0               0
Gene2       1           222222      0.12            0.01
Gene3       2           333333      0.03            0.25
Gene4       2           333337      0.03            0.25
```

**Edit:** Here is the beginning of the code I used for now (not correct output):

```
awk '
NR==FNR{ range[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5]; next }
FNR==1
{
  for(x in range) {
    split(x, check, SUBSEP);
    if($2==check[1] && $3>=check[2] && $3<=check[3]) { print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"check[4]"\t"check[5]}
  }
}
' File2 File1
```

However, I did not manage to associate a 0 (with "else") when the gene was not present. I get the wrong number of lines. I  Can you give me more hints?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: how big are the input files (MBytes, # of lines) and are both already sorted by Chromosome?

Comment: You should show what you've got as code — if you don't have it with you, go to where you do have it.

Comment: How big are the files? As @markp-fuso implied, a brute force approach that searches all the file 2 ranges for every file 1 position is kind of trivial.  If the files are big, that  could take a very long time. A more complicated approach would go much faster, but you haven't said enough to know if that's necessary.  Another thing that's missing whether the file 2 ranges overlap. You imply that with the example, but is it always true?

Comment: The problem you have for an efficient approach is there is no unique combination of fields from `File1` that can serve as a key from any field in `File2`, Chromosome values are not unique and therefore cannot be used as an index (both alone or with `SUBSEP` and any other field). So unless you have more columns not shown, you are stuck with the brute force approach that will be horribly inefficient (even if you read `File1` into any array and `split()` the value for each check against `File2`.

Comment: File 1 is about 5MB (~900 lines) and File 2 is a few KB (~50 lines). File 1 has about 500 columns and File 2 has about 20 columns. File 1 is not exactly sorted by chromosome: I have two successive series by mutation type (1->22 and then again 1->22).
I didn't have my code available, I will edit my post with it as soon as possible. 
The ranges in File 2 do not overlap, my example implies that several genes can have a position that is in the same range.
Indeed, because of the great number of columns, I have only shown the columns of interest.

Comment: consider updating the question with the additional details; not everyone is going to spend the time parsing comments in order to understand the entire issue/question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk`-only idea ...

**NOTE:** see my other answer for assumptions/understandings and my version of `file1`

```
awk '     # process file2
FNR==NR   { c=$1                            # save chromosome value
            $1=""                           # clear field #1
            file2[c]=$0                     # use chromosome as array index; save line in array
            next
          }

          # process file1
          { start=end=-9999999999           # default values in case
            a1=a2=""                        # no match in file2

            if ($2 in file2) {              # if chromosome also in file2
                split(file2[$2],arr)        # split file2 data into array arr[]

                startpos =arr[1]
                endpos   =arr[2]
                a1       =arr[3]
                a2       =arr[4]
            }

            # if not the header row and file1/position outside of file2/range then set a1=a2=0
            if (FNR>1 && ($3 < startpos || $3 > endpos)) a1=a2=0

            print $0,a1,a2
          }
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
Hugo_Symbol Chromosome  Position cell_frac_A1 cell_frac_A2
Gene2       1           222222 0.12 0.01
Gene3       2           333333 0.03 0.25
Gene1       1           111111 0 0
Gene4       2           333337 0.03 0.25
Gene5       4           444567 0 0
```

Changing the last line to `' file2 file1 | column -t` generates:

```
Hugo_Symbol  Chromosome  Position  cell_frac_A1  cell_frac_A2
Gene2        1           222222    0.12          0.01
Gene3        2           333333    0.03          0.25
Gene1        1           111111    0             0
Gene4        2           333337    0.03          0.25
Gene5        4           444567    0             0
```

Presorting `file1` by `Chromosome` and `Position` by changing last line to `' file2 <(head -1 file1; tail -n +2 file1 | sort -k2,3) | column -t` generates:

```
Hugo_Symbol  Chromosome  Position  cell_frac_A1  cell_frac_A2
Gene1        1           111111    0             0
Gene2        1           222222    0.12          0.01
Gene3        2           333333    0.03          0.25
Gene4        2           333337    0.03          0.25
Gene5        4           444567    0             0
```

One big **issue** (same as with my other answer) ... the actual code may become unweidly when dealing with 519 total columns especially if there's a need to intersperse a lot of columns; otherwise OP may be able to use some `for` loops to more easily print ranges of columns.

Answer (score 2):

A job for sql instead of awk, perhaps?

```
tr -s ' ' '|' <File1 >file1.csv
tr -s ' ' '|' <File2 >file2.csv
(
   echo 'Hugo_Symbol|Chromosome|Position|cell_frac_A1|cell_frac_A2'
   sqlite3 <<'EOD'
.import file1.csv t1
.import file2.csv t2
select distinct
   t1.hugo_symbol,
   t1.chromosome,
   t1.position,
   case
      when t1.position between t2.start_position and t2.end_position
      then t2.cell_frac_a1
      else 0
   end,
   case
      when t1.position between t2.start_position and t2.end_position
      then t2.cell_frac_a2
      else 0
   end
from t1 join t2 on t1.chromosome=t2.chromosome;
EOD
   rm file[12].csv
) | tr '|' '\t'
```

Comment: just curious ... for *large* volumes of data ... is `sqlite` 'smart' enough to dynamically create a (temp) index (or hash/join key) to speed up the join? if not, you may want to consider adding an index (on the inner table) for join performance reasons

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, was just thinking about adding an index but explain seems to indicate it already does: `SCAN TABLE t2`, `SEARCH TABLE t1 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (Chromosome=?)`

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions and/or understandings based on sample data and OP comments ...

- `file1` is **not** sorted by chromosome
- `file2` **is** sorted by chromosome
- common headers in both files are spelled the same (eg, `file1:Chromosome` vs `file2:Chromosom`)
- if a chromosome exists in `file1` but does **not** exist in `file2` then we keep the line from `file1` and the columns from `file2` are left blank
- both files are relatively small (`file1`: 5MB, 900 lines; `file2`: few KB, 50 lines)
- **NOTE:** the number of columns (`file1`: 500 columns; `file2`: 20 columns) could be problematic from the point of view of cumbersome coding ... more on that later ...

Sample inputs:

```
$ cat file1                           # scrambled chromsome order; added chromosome=4 line
Hugo_Symbol Chromosome  Position
Gene1       1           111111
Gene3       2           333333
Gene2       1           222222
Gene4       2           333337
Gene5       4           444567        # has no match in file2

$ cat file2
Chromosome  Start_Position  End_Position    cell_frac_A1    cell_frac_A2
1           222220          222230          0.12            0.01
2           333330          333340          0.03            0.25
3           444440          444450          0.01            0.01
```

First issue is to sort `file1` by `Chromosome` and `Position` and also keep the header line in place:

```
$ (head -1 file1; tail -n +2 file1 | sort -k2,3)

Hugo_Symbol Chromosome  Position
Gene1       1           111111
Gene2       1           222222
Gene3       2           333333
Gene4       2           333337
Gene5       4           444567
```

We can now `join` the 2 files based on the `Chromosome` column:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 --nocheck-order <(head -1 file1; tail -n +2 file1 | sort -k2,3) file2

Chromosome Hugo_Symbol Position Start_Position End_Position cell_frac_A1 cell_frac_A2
1 Gene1 111111 222220 222230 0.12 0.01
1 Gene2 222222 222220 222230 0.12 0.01
2 Gene3 333333 333330 333340 0.03 0.25
2 Gene4 333337 333330 333340 0.03 0.25
4 Gene5 444567
```

Where:

- `-1 2 -2 1` - join on `Chromosome` columns: `-1 2` == file #1 column #2; `-2 1` == file #2 column #1
- `-a 1` - keep columns from file #1 (sorted `file1`)
- `--nocheck-order` - disable verifying input is sorted by join column; optional; may be needed if a locale thinks `1` should be sorted before `Chromosome`
- **NOTE:** for the sample inputs/outputs we don't need a special output format so we can skip the `-o` option, but this may be needed depending on OP's output requirements for 519 total columns (but it may also become unwieldly)

From here OP can use `bash` or `awk` to do comparisons (is column #3 between columns #4/#5); one `awk` idea:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 --nocheck-order <(head -1 file1; tail -n +2 file1 | sort -k2,3) file2 | awk 'FNR>1{if ($3<$4 || $3>$5) $6=$7=0} {print $2,$1,$3,$6,$7}'

Hugo_Symbol Chromosome Position cell_frac_A1 cell_frac_A2
Gene1 1 111111 0 0                                         # Position outside of range
Gene2 1 222222 0.12 0.01
Gene3 2 333333 0.03 0.25
Gene4 2 333337 0.03 0.25
Gene5 4 444567 0 0                                         # no match in file2; if there were other columns from file2 they would be empty
```

And to match OP's sample output (appears to be a fixed width requirement) we can pass this to `column`:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 --nocheck-order <(head -1 file1; tail -n +2 file1 | sort -k2,3) file2 | awk 'FNR>1{if ($3<$4 || $3>$5) $6=$7=0} {print $2,$1,$3,$6,$7}' | column -t

Hugo_Symbol  Chromosome  Position  cell_frac_A1  cell_frac_A2
Gene1        1           111111    0             0
Gene2        1           222222    0.12          0.01
Gene3        2           333333    0.03          0.25
Gene4        2           333337    0.03          0.25
Gene5        4           444567    0             0
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind this may be untenable with OP's 519 total columns, especially if interspersed columns contain blanks/white-space (ie, `column -t` may not parse the input properly)

**Issues** (in addition to incorrect assumptions and previous **NOTES**):

- for relatively small files the performance of the `join | awk | column` should be sufficient
- for larger files all of this code can be rolled into a single `awk` solution though memory usage could be an issue on a small machine (eg, one `awk` idea would be to load `file2` into memory via arrays so memory would need to be large enough to hold all of `file2` ... probably not an issue unless `file2` gets to be 100's/1000's of MBytes in size)
- for 519 total columns the `awk/print` will get unwieldly especially if there's a need to move/intersperse a lot of columns